# ScriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn") fails because of java.lang.invoke.WrongMethodTypeException

Tags: java, java-8, nashorn, invokedynamic, methodhandle

I am unable to create `ScriptEngine` for `nashorn` in Java 8 (IBM J9JVM). In the following code, the engine is `null`.

```
private static void runOther(String[] args){
    ScriptEngineManager engineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
    engine.eval("function sum(a, b) { return a + b; }");
}
```

This failure is introduced by my library, which performs bytecode generation for MethodHandle in `java.lang.invoke` package. The changes in my library are:

1. the change are only for the standard `java.lang.invoke` package. None is changed for nashorn.
2. When nashorn is about to set a call site's target with `Methodhandle target`, my library will transform the `target` into another method handle `b`, if the `target` is created from `GuardWithTestHandle` and set the call site's target to `b`. Both 'target`and`b` has the same method type.

My last version of the library was completed in Oct 2016 and it was OK for Nashorn. But the new version I built has the `WrongMethodTypeException` when executing `getEngineByName`. This exception was handled inside of `getEngineByName` and null is returned.

The nashorn source code I got is not consist with the nashorn.jar in JVM. During the debug, what I found was that the exception was from:

> global = createNashornGlobal();

inside of `NashornScriptEngine.<init>`. After digesting deep, the exception was thrown when doing MethodHandle invocation at `UserAccessorProperty` (line318)

```
/*     */   public Object getObjectValue(ScriptObject self, ScriptObject owner)
/*     */   {
/*     */     try {
/* 215 */       return invokeObjectGetter(getAccessors(owner != null ? owner : self), getObjectGetterInvoker(), self);  //owner and self are the same instance. 
/*     */     } catch (Error|RuntimeException t) {
/* 217 */       throw t;
/*     */     } catch (Throwable t) {
/* 219 */       throw new RuntimeException(t);
/*     */     }
/*     */   }


/*     */   private static Object invokeObjectGetter(Accessors gs, MethodHandle invoker, Object self)
/*     */     throws Throwable
/*     */   {
/* 316 */     Object func = getter;
/* 317 */     if ((func instanceof ScriptFunction)) {
/* 318 */       return invoker.invokeExact(func, self);
/*     */     }
/*     */     
/* 321 */     return ScriptRuntime.UNDEFINED;
/*     */   }
```

At line 318, the `invoker` is `MutableCallSiteDynamicInvokerHandle` and its method type is `(Object,Object)Object`.  Both `func` and `self` are declared as `Object` object here and types of parameters and return value are matched completely.

I can not understand this exception, and have no idea next steps for this issue. Thanks if you can provide some ideas and suggestion for the issue here? Or some options/configurations..

See stacks [image: Debug screen shot for stack].

Comment: can you post the stacktrace? It should be something like `expected`... but `found`... Also the code for `getEngineByName` would help

Comment: Thanks @Eugene, do you have way to set `jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.DEBUG` to be true? This field is false as default, and Nashorn does not print call stack if DEBUG is false.

Comment: no I don't. You also make little sense of what *actually* you changed, or *what jvm you run in into* or even the source code of `getEngineByName`. Even the description where you say : `bytecode generation for MethodHandle` is a bit confusing. So.. can you post the code and explain exactly where it worked and where it does not

Comment: The code is large and I add two explanations here

Comment: [I can only repeat myself: I don’t think that it is a good idea…](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986780/java-bytecode-variable-index-0s-classname-is-something-strange#comment65400242_38986780). Really, you have hacked into some crucial lowlevel JRE facility and get unexpected results and expect *us* to tell you what’s going on, without even knowing, what you have changed?

Comment: @Holger, I agree that it is not reasonable to ask the issue when I replaced some default standard Java class, and did not provide details of my modification. I am doing an experiment, which adds million of code to the standard Java package and makes it is hard to paste code here. Anyway, I would try my best to explain my change. Thanks